# JSTL set variable session when a <tr> is selected

Tags: jsp, jstl

Hi everyone i'm currently coding a web app and I encounter problems to set up the session attribute with a jstl variable.

In my app I display a list of objects "poster" using the jstl foreach tag. thus on the UI I have these list and i can drag and drop lines of the poster table in order to see a detailed version of the poster I choosed. here I need to get a variable "posterId" to pass it on a servlet (with session or wiht another method) here's my code:

```
<c:forEach var="poster" items="${listePosters}" varStatus="loop">
    <tr data-sujets='${listeSujets[loop.index].titre}'
        data-etat= '${listeValide[loop.index]}'
        id="draggable-${loop.index}" draggable='true'
        ondragstart="drag(event,${loop.index});"
        onmouseout="fmouseup(${loop.index});"
        ondragend="enddrag(event,${loop.index});"
        onmousedown="fmousedown(${loop.index});"
        onmouseup="fmouseup(${loop.index});"
        onClick= "<c:set var="idPoster" value="${poster.idPoster}" 
        scope="session"/>;">        
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

so here I have 2 posters and in theory when I click on line with poster 1 session attribute should be set to 1 and when I click on line with poster 2 session attribute should be set to 2 I know my `${poster.idPoster}` get the right values because I did a `window.alert()` instead of the `c:set...` line and I get the right values so that's why I don't understand why session do not set up correctly

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it,
what you are tring is set a server side value on client side and it's not possible.
you need a form(html) or ajax(javascript) or another method to send back the selected value to the server.

Actually you are pre-setting the session value to the last one printed server side.